# How to add maven-formatted required project to another project under Eclipse?

Tags: java, maven, buildpath

I have source code of some library, which is made under Maven. When I downloaded it with Eclipse, it didn't recognize it as Java project. Event if I assign Maven nature to, the Java nature does not appear (apparently for me).

The means, that the only thing I can do with this project -- is to run Maven goals.

This would be OK if standalone.

Let's call project above as "source" project.

Now I want to use source project's jar (it produces some jars) as the dependency for another project, which will be called "destination" project.

If I try to use standard `Java Build Path` dialog, where I can refer other projects, source project is not even listed. This is why I say Eclipse does not see it is as Java project.

But may be it is possible to refer source project with `pom.xml` of destination project?

Source project has the following pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>piccolo2d-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.piccolo2d</groupId>
    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>./parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>piccolo2d-complete</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>Piccolo2D</name>
  <scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:http://piccolo2d.googlecode.com/svn/piccolo2d.java/trunk</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://piccolo2d.googlecode.com/svn/piccolo2d.java/trunk</developerConnection>
    <url>http://code.google.com/p/piccolo2d/source/browse/piccolo2d.java/trunk</url>
  </scm>
  <build />
  <reporting />
  <modules>
    <module>parent</module>
    <module>core</module>
    <module>extras</module>
    <module>swt</module>
    <module>examples</module>
    <module>swt-examples</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

Is it possible to write something in destination's project's pom.xml, so that it refer source project?

If I set normal  tag then it probably will go to global repository and take it from there.

What to do? May be I should rename source project artifact or something?

May be "SNAPSHOT" name works for this? I want to add some functionality to Piccolo.

**UPDATE**

I have referred to one of subproject's ids in my "destination" project and Eclipse found it somewhere. But I am not sure it took it from my workspace. Most probably it took it from global repository. Also I can't download any source code insid "destination" project. This also means that probably Eclipse does not put artifacts from workspace into repository.

Comment: Have you tried running `mvn eclipse:eclipse` on the project to create an Eclipse project from the pom?

Answer (score 0):

You 'source' project has  pom. This means that it is not a Java project on its own, it is a container for projects like 'core', 'extras' etc.

In you destination project, you need to add a  to one or more of the sub-projects, not the source project itself. For example, to add the core module (assuming it has artifactId piccolo2d-core, add the following to the destination pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>    
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.piccolo2d</groupId>
    <artifactId>piccolo2d-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

If the projects are imported in the same Eclipse workspace, Eclipse will add the referenced sub-projects as Project References in the Java Build Path.

Comment: How to add any of subprojects?

Comment: In your destination pom.xml, add <dependency>
 <groupId>org.piccolo2d</groupId>
 <artifactId>piccolo2d-core</artifactId>
 <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

Comment: I did this, but apparently data was taken from somewhere else, not from Eclipse

Comment: Is the piccolo2d-core project imported into eclipse in the same workspace? When you import the source project, you need to make sure you import recursively, so eclipse will create a project for each maven sub-module.